# For loops in matlab with a specific starting point

Tags: matlab

I have the following definitions

```
long  = 1000;
  init  = 500;      
  N = init+long;        
  T = init+1:N-1;   
  T1    = init+2:N;
```

I then fill the vectors that I want according to this loop,

```
   for t=1:N+1
     Rk(t)=1+A(t)*alpha*kh(t).^(alpha-1)-delta;  
     Yi(t)=A(t)*(1-alpha)*kh(t).^alpha - A(t)*alpha*kh(t).^(alpha-1)+eta(t);
     Rap(t)=Rk(t).^(1-gamma)+(1-gamma)*Rk(t).^(-gamma)*theta(t)*Yi(t)-0.5*gamma*(1-gamma)*(theta(t)*Yi(t)).^2;  
   end
```

Finally, I compute some new vectors according to this loop

```
for t=T1
           fi1(t)=(v(t).^(1-gamma))*(Rk(t))*(Yi(t)');  % Expectations 1 
           fi2(t)=((v(t).^(1-gamma))*(Yi(t)).^2);   
           fi3(t)=(((v(t).^(1-gamma))*Rap(t)).^(1/(1-gamma)));
       end
```

So, from the last loop I aim into getting a vector of size T1, but instead I receive a 1x1500 vector.

My scope is essentially to take all the numbers in vectors, v, Rk, Yi, from exactly the region that T1 specifies (i.e 502:1500), so I should get the 1x999, and not the 1x1500 vector.

So I suppose even if someone stars with an index 502 to count the loop, Matlab still understand this as 1, and loops until N, which is the end point of T1.

Can somebody tell me how should amend the code in order to get what I described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t` starts at 502, but *all* MATLAB arrays start at 1. So MATLAB pads `fi1`, `fi2`, and `fi2`, with zeros from index 1 to 501 and then puts your data in starting at 502. You can either live with this or write:

```
for t=T1
  fi1(t-(init+1))=(v(t).^(1-gamma))*(Rk(t))*(Yi(t)');
  ......
end
```

Comment: Or, if you're not going to preallocate the array anyway, use the nice MATLAB syntax to append new elements to an array: `fi1=[]; ...; for t=T1, fi1(end+1)=...; ...; end`.